# Проверка строки содержащей число

Tags: java, числа

Имеется 3 `textField`, в которые нужно вводить только целые или дробные числа. По нажатию кнопки произвожу вычисления с числами, вытянутыми из `textField`'ов, попутно помещаю все 3 числа в 1 строку. Как правильно проверить, содержит ли эта строка только целые или дробные числа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try { 
    Double.valueOf(inputText);
    //это число
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //это явно не число
}
```

Не заморачивайтесь, заталкивайте полученный текст в дабл и перехватывайте возможную ошибку. Вся проблема в том, что регулярка не очень быстрая. К тому же , если регулярка скажет, что это число, то вам его все равно парсить. Так может парсить сразу, регулярка просто лишнее колесо в данном случае .

Answer (score 1):

Если очень хочется проверять регулярками, то можно использовать следующий код:

```
private static boolean isNumber(String str) {
    return str.matches("[-+]?[\\d]+([.][\\d]+)?");
}
```

Вывод будет следующий:

```
System.out.println(isNumber("0"));
System.out.println(isNumber("0.0"));
System.out.println(isNumber("+1.111"));
System.out.println(isNumber("-1"));
System.out.println(isNumber("-2.0"));
System.out.println(isNumber("hello world"));
System.out.println(isNumber("99 hello world"));
```

> true
>   true
>   true
>   true
>   true
>   false
>   false